# How does one layout a UITableViewCell without using Auto Layout in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios8

Apologies if this is an obvious question, but as someone who has became completely used to Auto Layout and constraints, for performance I want to try laying things out manually. However, every tutorial I look up has to do with Auto Layout instead of any manual layouts.

How do I layout a `UITableViewCell` without depending on Auto Layout at all? I have my nib (with Auto Layout turned off), and do I position things in an overridden `layoutSubviews` method? Or `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? How is spacing between views accomplished? Are there any general tutorials available?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty good tutorial for your needs: http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/

However there is one more method that this tutorial does not mention:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return heightOfYourCell;
}
```

This one is pretty important if you want your cell to be bigger or smaller than the default 44pt.